# How can I grab only SharePoint Assemblies from GAC?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007, gac, windows-server-2008-r2

How can I grab all SharePoint `.wsp` related assemblies from GAC in windows server 2008 r2?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/10/extract-download-wsp-files-from-installed-solutions.html) is the link for grabbing all installed SharePoint solutions. If you don't explicitly need the associated `assemblies`, it should suffice.